# Line breaks are ignored in downloaded text file from AJAX response on Firefox, working fine with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to download text file from an API response which has a text/plain format. When i download file using Chrome it has line breaks as in response, but when downloading from Firefox it ignores all line breaks.

Here is the code for downloading text file:

```
function downloadTxt(ele) {
            const name = ele.attr('data-name');
            $.ajax({
                url: urls[name],
                method:'GET',
                success: function(response, textStatus, request) {
                    $('#customLoader').remove();
                    const filename = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split("filename=")[1]
                    const uri = 'data:text/txt;charset=utf-8,' + response;
                    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                    downloadLink.href = uri;
                    downloadLink.download = filename;

                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the file format when downloaded from Chrome:

[image: Text File]

And here is the file format when downloaded from Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Which application are you using to view the file? Does it have a way to set the line endings? Which line endings does the file itself use? Does it differ based on browser?